# Assign look-up fields in Page layout

Tags: custom-object, lookup, custom-field, page-layout, fields

I have a custom object Called **App__c** and **Context__c** , **App__c** has look-up with **Context__c** , Now need to add **App__c** object fields in **Context__c**  page layout. Is this possible? Anyone can help?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

When `App__c` has a lookup relation to `Context__c`, one `context__c` may hold multiple `App__c` which makes `App__c` a related list on `Context__c` object.

So no there is no way to add `App__c` fields to `Context__c` layout.

Answer (score 1):

That single Lookup field forms a many-to-one relationship between `App__c` and `Context__c`. If there is a particular `App__c` record that is significant among the many and should be tagged on `Context__c`, consider adding a Lookup on `Context__c` to `App__c`, e.g. `LatestApp__c` field on `Context__c` which means a Context has a single App being the latest. Use a process or trigger to populate this field. Then you should be able to configure App fields on a Context page layout via formula fields.